Properly convert numerical values from a JSON to a QVariantMap
I am currently working on a server project using C++ and Qt.
Upon reception of a post request, I collect the json data from the request, and I would like to convert it to a QVariantMap.
Currently, the code snippet I have is the following:
QJsonParseError err;
QJsonDocument body;

body = QJsonDocument::fromJson(request->getRequest()->collectedData(), &err);
if ( !(err.error == QJsonParseError::NoError)) return;
QVariantMap userConfig = body.object().toVariantMap();

Note that the collectedData() returns the desired QByteArray value.
The problem I have is on the decoding of numerical values.
While a float pi = 3.14 will be considered as a float within the QVariantMap, a float almost_pi = 3.0 will be considered as an int.
This means that if I want to write into a JSON file reusing my QVariantMap, the original Json
{
  "pi":3.14,
  "almost_pi":3.0 // a float
}


will be translated to
{
  "pi":3.14,
  "almost_pi":3 // an int
}


This is problematic for me as the rest of my pipeline depends on the newly generated json.
Is there a way to make sure the values inside a QVariantMap are correctly set ? Also, I have no way of knowing in advance what kind of values I will be receiving, so using toDouble(), toInt() methods is not an option here.
Thanks in advance!

Technically speaking, the json specification says that numbers are just numbers, without any differentiation between floats and integers. That said, QVariant should preserve the original type, so the problem is probably just serializing back: the json structure is relatively simple, it shouldn't be that difficult to use a recursive algorithm that writes the json back and specifically addresses float variants.

It unfortunately does not, QVariant stores it as double (for what is detected as float) or qlonglong (for what is detected as int). I can probably work around that but I was wondering if something generic was already existing that I did not know of. @musicamante

With "should preserve" I meant that it doesn't automatically convert it to an integer. AFAIK, Qt doesn't provide a way to preserve number types while serializing, probably basing its implementation on the standard specification, so I'm afraid that the only option you have is to serialize it on your own. You may consider filing a report, in any case.
